# Count Same Values On Mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, count

I want to count the max value on the table based on single field.

I have a image_count field on my table; that's counts different images not different thumbnails with same image.

For example i have an image named stack.jpg and have three thumbnails in different sizes.

So i have to save that resized images to db with same image_count.

Let's give a count number to that files: 1.

When i upload another image with three thumbnail sizes again; that uploaded and resized images must has the image_count: 2.

So:

```
ID | Thumbnail |        Image         | count |
-----------------------------------------------
 1 |   Small   |   stack_small.jpg    |   1   |
 2 |   Medium  |   stack_medium.jpg   |   1   |
 3 |   Big     |   stack_big.jpg      |   1   |
 4 |   Small   |   overflw_small.jpg  |   2   |
 5 |   Medium  |   overflw_medium.jpg |   2   |
 6 |   Big     |   overflw_big.jpg    |   2   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

When i want to add a new image to db, count field has to be "3". Not 7.

I have to group by count i think but i'm using symfony2 with doctrine and when i try to get singleScalarResult with count, it is throwing exception.

My Code:

```
public function countImages($entity_id, $gallery_id)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $count = $qb
        ->select('COUNT(i)')
        ->from('CSGalleryBundle:GalleryImage', 'i')
        ->leftJoin('CSGalleryBundle:Gallery', 'g', 'WITH', 'g.id = i.gallery_id')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq('i.foreign_key', $entity_id),
            $qb->expr()->eq('g.id', $gallery_id)
        )
        ->groupBy('i.image_count')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $count + 1;
}
```

Error:

[image]

What is the problem here? How can i solve? Is there any better way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You must use Doctrine way for increase performance. You can use this query:

```
$count = $qb
        ->select('MAX(i.image_count)')
        ->from('CSGalleryBundle:GalleryImage', 'i')
        ->leftJoin('CSGalleryBundle:Gallery', 'g', 'WITH', 'g.id = i.gallery_id')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq('i.foreign_key', $entity_id),
            $qb->expr()->eq('g.id', $gallery_id)
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

return $count === null ? 1 : $count + 1;
```

Comment: OMG God bless you! Thank you :) This is the way i was looking for!!! You are the man!

Answer (score 1):

You can change query with below for basic solve:

```
$count = $qb
   ->select('i')
   ->from('CSGalleryBundle:GalleryImage', 'i')
   ->leftJoin('CSGalleryBundle:Gallery', 'g', 'WITH', 'g.id = i.gallery_id')
   ->where(
       $qb->expr()->eq('i.foreign_key', $entity_id),
       $qb->expr()->eq('g.id', $gallery_id)
   )
   ->groupBy('i.image_count')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();

return count($count);
```

Maybe you can review Doctrine Query Builder Documentation for more efficiently resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use count method with distinct

```
$count = $qb
   ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT i)')
   ->from('CSGalleryBundle:GalleryImage', 'i')
   ->leftJoin('CSGalleryBundle:Gallery', 'g', 'WITH', 'g.id = i.gallery_id')
   ->where(
       $qb->expr()->eq('i.foreign_key', $entity_id),
       $qb->expr()->eq('g.id', $gallery_id)
   )
   ->groupBy('i.image_count')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getSingleScalarResult();

return $count;
```

I think it will throw an exception if there is no matched data.

Answer (score 0):

Just an attempt. I haven't check this. Why do you have leftJoin in your code?

```
$count = $qb
    ->select('MAX(i.count)')
    ->from('CSGalleryBundle:GalleryImage', 'i')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();

return $count + 1;
```

Comment: Bro this will not work for me from many ways... Please read the question again.

Comment: So what do you want to accomplish? Get the next number for column 'count' (i thing this name can cause misunderstandings), or just get the numbers of images (where image can have more then one record, but all with the same value in 'count' column)? Try to dump the query.